# Subresource Integrity and performance

Tags: subresource-integrity

I'm reading about [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) but I'm worried about the performance loss. How does this (having to hash every file before executing it) slow down the page load, especially on devices with low level CPUs?

Answer (score 3):

I ran a performance benchmark today and observed the following averages when generating hashes for a 120KB Twitter Bootstrap minified CSS file.

```
File Size: 121200
SHA1   Time: 0.50199 ms
SHA256 Time: 0.89691 ms
SHA384 Time: 1.59249 ms
SHA512 Time: 1.58901 ms
```

`SHA1` is considered insecure and may not work. So, if you use `SHA256`, you can expect an overall delay of less than 1 ms per resource on a common device. I ran this benchmark on my one and half year old Corei5 ASUS Laptop that is not very good at performance. Also, 120KB is a little above average. Most static files are smaller, and smaller file size would mean faster hash generation.

Based on these benchmarks, if I weigh the benefits of using SRI with the cost of 1ms per resource, I will prefer to use SRI as the cost is almost negligible. Changes of hackers getting into the server of a large CDN provider are not negligible as you said in a comment. I would point you to a [past incident](https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/bootstrapcdn-security-post-mortem/) where hackers injected their own javascript to attack IE users.

Answer (score 0):

**How...?** - it uses the CPU to calculate the hashes.
**How much?** - Measure, depending on CPU and resource size etc.
**But...** - for performance you could try to combine and minimize the resources, and use less CPU-intensive hash algorithms.

Don't worry, be happy!

Comment: The point was: is it worth doing it? The chances that a big public CDN (like googleapis or cdnjs) get hacked are close to zero, MITM attacks can't occur if using https, so for now I don't see any benefit in adding this

Comment: @the_nuts While the chances of CDN-s getting hacked or taken over, HTTPS being broken etc might be low (but not zero), it really comes down to **your opinion** and analysis about how much performance and security are of value for your specific application. I doubt that my opinion (which usually inclines to value security more than performance) would be a good answer in the Stack Overflow format.